# How to understand the answer of decide not to see someone anymore?

Tags: meaning

The question is like " she decides not to see someone anymore ? "

If the answer is " Yes"

Does that mean: She is still willing to see someone

Comment: Focus on Not to see. 'Someone' may be Pat, and she decided not to date Pat further (anymore).  Introduce her to Leslie.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin OP has identified a possible area of ambiguity. A different example: A asks, "You don't agree with me?" B says "No." -- so does B mean "No, I don't" or "No, I actually agree?"

Answer (score 1):

*to decide not to see someone* is often to mean *to decide not to date someone*.

Suppose Sue decides not to see Jim anymore.  She will then refuse to go out with him to movies or restaurants and so forth.  She is likely, however, to be willing to date (see) other people.

But *to decide not to see someone* has general uses.  You can decide you do not wish to see someone who has been a friend.  A child of divorced parents can decide, at an appropriate age, not to see one (or both) of his parents again.  A person can decide not to see his or her dentist anymore, and instead find another dentist.

Comment: Maybe you misinterpreted the question? I don't think OP is asking what 'decide not to see someone' means: OP specifically wants to know whether the answer 'Yes' to the question 'She doesn't want to see someone anymore?' actually means 'yes she wants to see (someone some more)'? Of course it would seem a *very hopeful* interpretation: I suppose OP feels that if she really didn't want to see someone anymore, the answer to that particular Q would've been 'No' rather than 'Yes', what do you think? Hurry, because *"somebody's happiness might possibly lie in the balance..."*

Comment: Oh, I see.  I think I did misinterpret it.  It belongs on ELL.  However, note that the answer explains that she doesn't want to see him anymore.  This is why the military (also civilian agencies) try to avoid such ambiguity, and why most answers are not "yes" or "no", but, e.g., "Right--I don't want to see you anymore."

Comment: OP's sample question is not properly worded. A question mark has been tacked onto a statement: *she has decided not to see someone any more...?* Answering 'yes' here would seem to confirm this statement, but OP is trying to interpret it ambiguously: yes,she will continue to see someone -- ignoring the fact that the yes/no actually applies to *decided* and not to *see.* Of course the proper form would be, "Has she decided not to see someone any more?" -- Answer: Yes, she has decided // No, she hasn't decided. If the question were worded properly, 'Yes' would leave no scope at all for ambiguity.